# Why am I getting "unable to parse request" when creating a new sheet?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I'm trying to create a new sheet with what I think is the correct JSON string, but I keep receiving "Unable to parse request." Does anyone know what would cause the error?

This is JSON string I am sending:

```
{"name":"MyNewSheet","columns":[{"title":"Name","primary":true,"type":"TEXT_NUMBER"},{"title":"Phone","type":"TEXT_NUMBER"},{"title":"Address","type":"TEXT_NUMBER"}]}
```

This is a response from Smartsheet.

```
{"errorCode":1008,"message":"Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Unexpected End of File."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON looks correct. You'll want to look at the `Content-Type` you're sending in the header of your request. To create a new sheet you'll need `Content-Type: application/json`.

A good example of this can be found in the [Create Sheet](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.b8cz8hhlzsw0) section of the Smartsheet API docs. Look closer at the example on the right of that page.